# NextJS: Deploy SSR in EC2

Tags: deployment, next.js, devops, server-side-rendering

Want to deploy NextJS app. We are using ‍`getStaticProps` for some pages and `getServerSideProps` for some other pages. So how to deploy this on EC2 instance? And we are getting ".next" folder after running `npm run build` command so how will this be helpful to deploy our App?

```
package.json:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first create an Instance in ec2 ubuntu
connect with SSH
then use few commands
like:- `sudo apt-get update` **after this**
`sudo apt-get upgrade -y`  **then**  `sudo apt update` **after this**
`sudo apt upgrade -y`

after these command Install nodejs
`curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -`
and `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

now you can upload the project with **FTP** or you can clone from **git**

use `npm pm2 install -g` then go to project directory and run `pm2 start server.js`

it will run your project

Comment: When you say clone the project, you mean to clone the complete source code? or just upload the .next folder on the server? Do I have to ftp only .next folder on the server? If you mean to say to clone or upload complete project that not make sense to me. Please guide as I am facing issue while uploading files under .next folder